# OData support for iOS (alternative to OData4ObjC)

Tags: ios, odata, odata4j

I was planning on using OData4ObjC to access OData from my iPhone app. But it seems that OData4ObjC has become an inactive project (*no activity at all for almost a year and no support for anything past iOS 4*).

**Does anyone else know of an equally robust OData Client library?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ios6 fork on github for Odata4ObjC:

https://github.com/ElizabethDuncan/OData4ObjC

No real idea what changes etc. have been made to the original or why it was forked like this (as opposed to making the changes directly in the original repository)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to write native app then develop a hybrid app with phonegap and jaydata

Comment: Thanks for your response! I looked into JayData (I have used it and LOVED it) but speed is a priority for my app. I'd prefer native....