# oData support for iOS 8 (preferably iOS 9 beta)

Tags: ios8, odata, ios9

I want to use oData service from iPhone app, and was looking for a good framework that supports at least iOS 8 and preferably iOS 9 beta. Can anyone suggest a good resource to look into? I checked for some resources but I would like to go for an open source / free option if possible.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432997/odata-support-for-ios-alternative-to-odata4objc) question asked before but again it was for iOS 6, and haven't maintained after that. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I too am looking to hook up OData calls in an app ... any luck finding an ARC compatible solution? I haven't looked into the library at all, but is one option for us to update their existing codebase?

Comment: Not yet, just using basic `NSURLSession` for now.